# FFmpeg cut h264 mp4 in place

Tags: ffmpeg

I just need to trim a bit off the front. I'm aware of of -t and -ss, but this video is rather large (~40GB), and lives on a spinning HDD, so just the file copying takes a long time. So I'm trying to avoid the copy by modifying the file in place.

As far as I know this should be technically possible in terms of the MP4 container, but I'm not sure about the filesystem (on Linux) or if the functionality exists in FFmpeg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*this should be technically possible in terms of the MP4 container*

No, MP4 metadata contains various indices tabulating info on packets including their location  (expressed as byte offsets). Removing any packets involves removing their index entries and adjusting the remaining ones. This can't be done in-place.